# i am trying to make an insert method recursively to my general tree what should i do?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, insert, tree

my insert code is only correct when trying to add less than 10 nodes but if i try to add more than 10 nodes i get stack over flow error.
im trying to make each node have a maximum of 10 children.
this is what i came up with.

```
public class GeneralTree {
public GTN root;
int max=10;

public GeneralTree(GTN root){

    this.root = root;
}
public GeneralTree(){}
public void insert(GTN node){
    if(root== null){
        root = node;
    }
    else
        insertR(root,node);
}
private void insertR(GTN Root,GTN node){
    if(root.children.isEmpty() || root.children.size()<max){
        root.children.add(node);
    }
    else {
            for(int k = 0;k<max;k++){
                insertR(root.children.get(k),node);
            }

    }

}
```

my node class.

```
public class GTN {
public GTN parent;
public Comparable<String>  key;
public ArrayList<GTN> children;

public GTN(Comparable key){
    this.parent = null;
    this.key=key;
    this.children = new ArrayList<GTN>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem originates here:

```
private void insertR(GTN Root,GTN node){
```

Look at it closely